# How to Cross Compile elfutils

Tags: make, cross-compilation, configure, elf, perf

My system (uname --all)

```
Linux shyamdaramubtnb 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My target

```
ARM Cortex A7
```

I am in the process of cross compiling `perf` tools for ARM, but `perf` while compilation requires the `elfutils` package to read the VMLinux file later, can any one suggest me a way to cross compile elfutils

Downloaded package from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/elfutils/0.163-4ubuntu1).

Currently I am following the below procedure:

```
$ aclocal
$ autoheader
$ autoconf
$ automake --add-missing
$ ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi \
--prefix=/home/kwangwoo/tools/arm-2010q1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/
$ make
$ make install
```

but i stuck at the process of executing ./configure, which throws me an error of

```
./configure: line 5115: syntax error near unexpected token `zlib,ZLIB,z,gzdirect,gzip'
./configure: line 5115: `eu_ZIPLIB(zlib,ZLIB,z,gzdirect,gzip)'
```

What may be the reason ? Strange that I did not find a Makefile in the folder downloaded does configure is supposed to create a make file ?(I see files like `Makefile.in`, `Makefile.am`).

LATEST DEVELOPMENTS 1:
i started following the [link](https://sites.google.com/site/hhmasterthesis/project-updates/2012-06-02) which has few hacks for my problems and trying to do the same as what i am trying

previously i faced some warnings which i ignored, and i understood they are the real cause of problems, on running `aclocal` i recieved an error saying

`warning: macro AM_PO_SUBDIRS not found in library.`

which were resolved by installing `intltool` and `gettext`

after running `automake --add-missing` i received an warning saying that

```
libdwfl/Makefile.am:73: ZLIB does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
libdwfl/Makefile.am:76: BZLIB does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
libdwfl/Makefile.am:79: LZMA does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
tests/Makefile.am:59: BIARCH does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
tests/Makefile.am:122: BIARCH does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
tests/Makefile.am:135: LZMA does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
tests/Makefile.am:139: ZLIB does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
```

so as suggested by the link i tried `autoreconf -f -i` and then   `automake --add-missing` again which worked like charm

then i ran the ./configure as above which actually did not stop any where, provided i have also done few thinks like commenting parts of Makefile and backends/Makefile which involve in some script related to i386 and x86_64 which have solved my problem in building elfutils for ARM !

Can anyone explain what actually is happening in the above steps ?

Comment: You may have an old version of the autotools. Did you check this ?

Comment: please find the updated question

Comment: Did you run a `make  CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` and `sudo make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- install` after the `./configure` ? Because, once you finished to configure your build-system, you just have to build the binaries through a `make` and, then, install the package through a `make install` (you need to be root, which explains the `sudo`).

Comment: just after configuration , i just done sudo make and then sudo make install , my problem is solved my perf tool is now working thanks

Comment: I also have this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

The autotools suite is a framework of scripts and tools to automate the settings and the compilation of a software package virtually on any type of system (in theory).

It is quite complex.

Usually, the first phase of it is to **configure** the build-system in order to check that everything that you need to compile the software is present on your system and, also, to know where it is (and in what version it is present).

Then, the build-system (based on Makefiles) is configured and ready to go.

You seems to stop at the configure phase because on some error internal to the configure script.

Note that the command you ran, previous to the `configure` script, are usually for developpers, they are probably needed because of the cross-compilation.

Finally, the error message seems to stop at the detection of the zip library (the script has the choice between the list display, as zip is a standard algorithm, it can just pick one of the lib, but it seems that it is not happy with the script it find).

I cannot tell much more as you did not specified more about your distribution and the context in which you are working.

Comment: please find the updated question